# .htaccess rewrite slash is appended to query string

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

localhost/projects/website/page is working fine. but when i add a slash at the end, the slash is added to query string. so the value of page becomes page = page/

How to append slash at the end without the query string catching it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule regex to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

The `?` after `.*` makes it non-greedy and leave the last `/` (in the URL path) to be matched against the optional `/?` part of your regex now.

Comment: Could you spare an upvote please if my post helped? Someone just voted it down for no reason at all!